# Error: Value rank (4) should be larger than the Variable rank (1) at most by number of dynamic axes (2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, lstm, cntk

I would like to know How to provide input varibales to CNTK Network Modelling and training the model like given [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_106A_LSTM_Timeseries_with_Simulated_Data.ipynb)

Since i  have two independent variable and 3 target variables, X and Y are of shape:

```
X["train"].shape
Out[60]: (34567, 10, 2, 1)

Y["train"].shape
Out[61]: (34567, 3, 1)
```

i gave time_steps and time_shift as 10.

```
N = 10  ### Specify the internal-state dimensions of the LSTM cell which is 10
def create_model(x):
    with C.layers.default_options(initial_state = 0.1):
        m = C.layers.Recurrence(C.layers.LSTM(N))(x)
        m = C.sequence.last(m)
        m = C.layers.Dropout(0.2, seed=1)(m)
        m = C.layers.Dense(1)(m)
        return m


BATCH_SIZE = 100;EPOCHS = 100

def next_batch(x, y, ds):
    def as_batch(data, start, count):
        part = []
        for i in range(start, start + count):
            part.append(data[i])
        return np.array(part)
    for i in range(0, len(x[ds])-BATCH_SIZE, BATCH_SIZE):
        yield as_batch(x[ds], i, BATCH_SIZE), as_batch(y[ds], i, BATCH_SIZE)



x = C.sequence.input_variable(1)
z = create_model(x)
l = C.input_variable(1, dynamic_axes=z.dynamic_axes, name="y")
learning_rate = 0.02
lr_schedule = C.learning_parameter_schedule(learning_rate)
loss = C.squared_error(z, l)
error = C.squared_error(z, l)
momentum_schedule = C.momentum_schedule(0.9, minibatch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
learner = C.fsadagrad(z.parameters, 
                      lr = lr_schedule, 
                      momentum = momentum_schedule, 
                      unit_gain = True)
trainer = C.Trainer(z, (loss, error), [learner])



# train
loss_summary = []
for epoch in range(0, EPOCHS):
    for x1, y1 in next_batch(X, Y, "train"):
        trainer.train_minibatch({x: x1, l: y1})
    if epoch % (EPOCHS / 10) == 0:
        training_loss = trainer.previous_minibatch_loss_average
        loss_summary.append(training_loss)
        print("epoch: {}, loss: {:.5f}".format(epoch, training_loss))
```

But this produces error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 6, in 
>       trainer.train_minibatch({x: x1, l: y1})
>
> File "c:\program
>   files\python36\lib\site-packages\cntk\train\trainer.py", line 184, in
>   train_minibatch
>       device)
>
> File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\cntk\cntk_py.py",
>   line 2856, in train_minibatch
>       return _cntk_py.Trainer_train_minibatch(self, *args)
>
> ValueError: Value rank (4) should be larger than the Variable rank (1)
>   at most by number of dynamic axes (2); Variable = 'Input('Input4973',
>   [#, *], [1](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_106A_LSTM_Timeseries_with_Simulated_Data.ipynb))', Value shape = '[100 x 10 x 2 x 1]'.
>
> [CALL STACK]
>
> > CNTK::TrainingParameterSchedule::  Transform
> >         - CNTK::Internal::  UseSparseGradientAggregationInDataParallelSGD (x2)
> >         - CNTK::Function::  Forward
> >         - CNTK::  CreateTrainer
> >         - CNTK::Trainer::  TotalNumberOfUnitsSeen
> >         - CNTK::Trainer::  TrainMinibatch (x2)
> >         - PyInit__cntk_py (x2)
> >         - PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
> >         - Py_CheckFunctionResult
> >         - PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs
> >         - PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
> >         - Py_CheckFunctionResult
> >         - PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs

I know this error corresponds to dynamic axes and input variables. But i don't know what to give as input variable in C.sequence.input_variable(1)  and  C.input_variable(1, dynamic_axes=z.dynamic_axes, name="y")

Also, i want to predict three target variables

Answer (score 0):

To predict 3 target variables you will want to have 3 outputs in your last layer so you should change `m = C.layers.Dense(1)(m)` to `m = C.layers.Dense(3)(m)`

The other error is because your X["train"] has shape=(batch, sequence, 2, 1), but when you call create_model you pass something that has shape=(sequence, 1). The best way to fix this is make your X["train"] have shape=(batch, sequence, 2) (e.g. by calling np.squeeze) and then call create_model with C.sequence.input_variable(2).